# How can I get admin order view blocks into a custom module page

Tags: php, blocks

I've got a custom module, Mirasvit Ticket, and I've added a tab for order information.

I'd like to be able to place pretty much the entire order view into that tab. However, I'm unable to get the blocks to show up.

Here's what I've pasted into my custom view pulled from `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view.phtml`

The file I'm working on is:

`app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/mst_helpdesk/t‌​icket/edit/tab/order‌​info.phtml`

```
<div class="grid np">
  <div class="hor-scroll table-responsive">
    <table cellspacing="0" class="data order-tables">
        <col />
        <col width="1" />
        <col width="1" />
        <col width="1" />
        <col width="1" />
        <col width="1" />
        <col width="1" />
        <col width="1" />
        <col width="1" />
        <col width="1" />
        <thead>
            <tr class="headings">
                <th><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Product') ?></th>
                <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Item Status') ?></span></th>
                <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Original Price') ?></span></th>
                <th><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Price') ?></th>
                <th class="a-center"><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Qty') ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Subtotal') ?></th>
                <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Tax Amount') ?></span></th>
                <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Tax Percent') ?></span></th>
                <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Discount Amount') ?></span></th>
                <th class="last"><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Row Total') ?></span></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php $_items = $_order->getItemsCollection() ?>
        <?php $i=0;foreach ($_items as $_item):?>
            <?php if ($_item->getParentItem()) continue; else $i++;?>
            <tbody class="<?php echo $i%2?'even':'odd' ?>">
                <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
                <?php echo $this->getItemExtraInfoHtml($_item) ?>
            </tbody>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm thinking that my problem is that `$this` is clearly different from the `$this` in that file.

Is there a way I can just load the blocks directly?

Comment: when you want to see where your $this comes from do get_class($this)

Comment: what is the name of your phtml file, did you add a new file or you just changed one of the files? your path file is not showing it

Comment: My path file is in a custom module but it's in: `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/mst_helpdesk/ticket/edit/tab/orderinfo.phtml`

Comment: I can see `$this` is used to call `helper`, so it wouldn't hurt much being different. How have you defined `$_order` in there? I don't see you have assigned anything to it? Also, are you seeing at least heading parts? Can you show your layout code too?

Comment: just use Mage::helper('mynamespace_Mirasvit /data') instead whatever you have change those

Comment: @AdarshKhatri I have assigned `$_order` with the order object and it works with some of the stuff, but I still can't call those blocks

Comment: The main issue I'm having is `$this->getItemHtml($_item)` just isn't doing anything. I can get information from `$_item` by using getters but not the Html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get full working items table in your custom module page, you should add this to your layout.

```
                 <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_view_items" name="order_items" template="sales/order/view/items.phtml">
                    <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>adminhtml/sales_order_view_items_renderer_default</block><template>sales/order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml</template></action>
                    <action method="addColumnRender"><column>qty</column><block>adminhtml/sales_items_column_qty</block><template>sales/items/column/qty.phtml</template></action>
                    <action method="addColumnRender"><column>name</column><block>adminhtml/sales_items_column_name</block><template>sales/items/column/name.phtml</template></action>
                    <action method="addColumnRender"><column>name</column><block>adminhtml/sales_items_column_name_grouped</block><template>sales/items/column/name.phtml</template><type>grouped</type></action>
                    <block type="core/text_list" name="order_item_extra_info" />
                </block>
```

Then, you can call `getItemHtml()`.

It's hard to tell where exactly you should add above code without seeing your layout file. Have a look at `sales.xml` layout file. It will give you some idea.

All you need to do is, somehow your block should extend `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Items_Abstract`, so that you can call `$this->getItemHtml()` function. In default `view.phtml`, `$this` means `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Items` object which extends `abstract` class.